# Yii - Url rewrite in Yii Url Manager

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting

Hi I want to make Url from `Sspartner/update/2` to `partner/update/CMP1002`. So I used this rule but its not working..

```
rules => array(
'partner/update'=>'SsPartner/update/<id:[\w\d]+>',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
'partner/<action:\w+>'=>'SsPartner/<action>',
```

and put this rule above every thing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem in letter case

```
'partner/update/<id:[\w\d]+>'=>'sspartner/update',
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solution!!!** Finally I got

```
'partner/update/<id:[\w\d]+>'=>'SsPartner/update',
```

Comment: This is identical to rule in your question.